# Firebase Cloud Messaging android project doesn't send push notifications

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to develop an application, in which a server must send notifications to all android devices running that application at every 5 seconds. I decided to use (Google) Firebse Cloud Messaging for sending the notifications, so I tried the example project of the guide first

https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience

but I cannot make it work. I followed all the instructions. I have posted the code I used. I also did **file-->project structure-->notifications-->checked the box Google Cloud Messaging**. I tried the application at an android 5 device.

When I open the Firebase console and send the notification, I see the refreshed token at the log (from `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` class, method `onTokenRefresh()`), but when I run it again, and send notification to a single device by copying and  pasting the token, nothing happens. Also, when I send notification from the console to **user segment**, nothing happens again.

I also tried the corresponding ios example project for Firebase, from the same website, and it worked fine for the iphone(all the notifications were sent).Am I missing something here?

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
}
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService :

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"FROM "+remoteMessage.getFrom(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"MESSAGE: "+remoteMessage.getData(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        //MainActivity.TestMethod();
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"MESSAGE: "+remoteMessage.getData(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
 sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
            Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        }
    }

    Button subscribeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton);
    subscribeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // [START subscribe_topics]
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
            // [END subscribe_topics]

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Button logTokenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logTokenButton);
    logTokenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Get token
            String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

and the build.gradle (project messaging):

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options commonto             `all sub-projects/modules.`

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

and the build.gradle (Module app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Testing dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

...and here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- [START firebase_service] -->
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END firebase_service] -->
        <!-- [START firebase_iid_service] -->
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END firebase_iid_service] -->
        <activity
            android:name=".ResultActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_result"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you [update the app manifest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest) for the services?

Comment: Yes @qbix, I have already done this, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Look in your `google-services.json` file to confirm that the contained values match those in your Project Settings at the Firebase Console.  In particular:  Project ID, Package Name, App ID.

Comment: @qbix I ckecked all those 3 settings, and they were the same for the project and the json...

Comment: Hard to guess what the problem might be.  You don't need `play-services-gcm:9.4.0` but that shouldn't break anything.  The [setup instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) are complete.  I have followed them a number of times for different projects and had success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what the problem was. It seems that somehow the json file was not the right one for the sample project.When you create the project at the Firebase console, it produces a json file, which should be dowloaded and placed to the app folder. When I created the project for my own application (and not the sample project) and did everything all over again (and placed the json file that was produced by the console in the app folder), it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are trying to get notification when your application is in foreground. Please make sure it is in the background and try again. Otherwise you need to follow the procedure to get notification when your app is foreground.

From Firebase Documentation :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

> Firebase notifications behave differently depending on the foreground/background state of the receiving app. If you want foregrounded apps to receive notification messages or data messages, you’ll need to write code to handle the onMessageReceived callback.

Sending a notification message : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message

> **Send a notification message**
>
> 1. Install and run the app on the target device.
> 2. **Make sure the app is in the background on the device.**
> 3. Open the Notifications tab of the Firebase console and select New Message.
> 4. Enter the message text.
> 5. Select Single Device for the message target.
> 6. In the field labeled FCM Registration Token, enter the registration token you obtained in a previous section of this guide.